# Windows 10 will not activate on corporate network and slmgr.vbs gives me permission errors

Tags: windows-10, windows-activation

I'm running Windows 10 Enterprise at work.  Everyone else seems to have activated just fine, but my machine is not activating, even though I am on the same network.  This error appears on the activation screen:

[image]

It's my understanding that the software licensing utility (slmgr.vbs) could be used to troubleshoot this problem.  However, when I try to run it, I get the following error:
[image]

I have tried several online solutions to this problem, but nothing works.
Attempted solutions include:

- Setting Plug and Play policy to 'Not Defined' in Group Policy followed by gpupdate /force and a restart (Not Applicable)
- Verifying that permissions are correct for the location where slmgr resides
- Verifying permissions for some registry keys involved in activation

Things to note:
slmgr.vbs with the /dlv option works fine, but /ato or -REARM fails.
I am running this command through an administrator command prompt.

Is this some kind of subtle permissions error?  How can I fix this?

Comment: "I have tried several online solutions to this problem" Since we're not mind readers, please edit your question to include details explaining exactly what you've tried already, and what the results were.  It helps define the scope, and avoid us suggesting the same things you've already tried. Also please include an example of the exact error message(s) you're receiving.  Also, how did you install Windows 10? Which edition?

Comment: @Ƭᴇcʜιᴇ007 I have updated the question with some more info.